# Simple text to HTML conversion

Tags: c#, html, parsing

I have a very simple `asp:textbox` with the `multiline` attribute enabled.  I then accept just text, with no markup, from the textbox.  Is there a common method by which line breaks and returns can be converted to `<p>` and `<br/>` tags?

I'm not looking for anything earth shattering, but at the same time I don't just want to do something like:

```
html.Insert(0, "<p>");
html.Replace(Enviroment.NewLine + Enviroment.NewLine, "</p><p>");
html.Replace(Enviroment.NewLine, "<br/>");
html.Append("</p>");
```

The above code doesn't work right, as in generating correct html, if there are more than 2 line breaks in a row.  Having html like `<br/></p><p>` is not good; the `<br/>` can be removed.

Comment: You could also [use a Markdown converter](http://commonmark.org/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on exactly what you are doing with the content, my typical recommendation is to ONLY use the `<br />` syntax, and not to try and handle paragraphs.

Answer (score 34):

I know this is old, but I couldn't find anything better after some searching, so here is what I'm using:

```
public static string TextToHtml(string text)
{
    text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(text);
    text = text.Replace("\r\n", "\r");
    text = text.Replace("\n", "\r");
    text = text.Replace("\r", "<br>\r\n");
    text = text.Replace("  ", " &nbsp;");
    return text;
}
```

If you can't use HttpUtility for some reason, then you'll have to do the HTML encoding some other way, and there are lots of minor details to worry about (not just `<>&`).

HtmlEncode only handles the special characters for you, so after that I convert any combo of carriage-return and/or line-feed to a BR tag, and any double-spaces to a single-space plus a NBSP.

Optionally you could use a PRE tag for the last part, like so:

```
public static string TextToHtml(string text)
{
    text = "<pre>" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(text) + "</pre>";
    return text;
}
```

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer because surrounding text between PRE tags actually forces a double line, not a single line break.

Answer (score 13):

Your other option is to take the text box contents and instead of trying for line a paragraph breaks just put the text between PRE tags. Like this:

```
<PRE>
Your text from the text box...

and a line after a break...
</PRE>
```

Comment: I never knew that. That saves a lot of messing around.

Answer (score 7):

How about throwing it in a [`<pre>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) tag. Isn't that what it's there for anyway?

Comment: Why not? Are you more comfortable re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: I don't want to preserve line-breaks and spaces.  I want to convert the text to be sematically correct html.

Comment: PRE reformats the textbox into a mono-spaced font like Courier and treats newline chars as <p> not <br/>

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but I've recently been in a similar problem using C# with MVC4, so thought I'd share my solution.

We had a description saved in a database. The text was a direct copy/paste from a website, and we wanted to convert it into semantic HTML, using `<p>` tags. Here is a simplified version of our solution:

```
string description = getSomeTextFromDatabase();
foreach(var line in description.Split('\n')
{
    Console.Write("<p>" + line + "</p>");
}
```

In our case, to write out a variable, we needed to prefix `@` before any variable or identifiers, because of the Razor syntax in the ASP.NET MVC framework. However, I've shown this with a `Console.Write`, but you should be able to figure out how to implement this in your specific project based on this :)

Answer (score 0):

Combining all previous plus considering titles and subtitles within the text comes up with this:

```
public static string ToHtml(this string text)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    var sr = new StringReader(text);
    var str = sr.ReadLine();
    while (str != null)
    {
        str = str.TrimEnd();
        str.Replace("  ", " &nbsp;");
        if (str.Length > 80)
        {
            sb.AppendLine($"<p>{str}</p>");
        }
        else if (str.Length > 0)
        {
            sb.AppendLine($"{str}</br>");
        }
        str = sr.ReadLine();
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

the snippet could be enhanced by defining rules for short strings

Answer (score 0):

I understand that I was late with the answer for 13 years)
but maybe someone else needs it

```
sample line 1 \r\n
sample line 2 (last at paragraph) \r\n\r\n [\r\n]+
sample line 3 \r\n
```

Example code

```
private static Regex _breakRegex = new("(\r?\n)+");
private static Regex _paragrahBreakRegex = new("(?:\r?\n){2,}");

public static string ConvertTextToHtml(string description) {
    string[] descrptionParagraphs = _paragrahBreakRegex.Split(description.Trim());
    if (descrptionParagraphs.Length > 0)
    {
        description = string.Empty;
        foreach (string line in descrptionParagraphs)
        {
            description += $"<p>{line}</p>";
        }
    }
    return _breakRegex.Replace(description, "<br/>");
}
```